# how to loop through a folder and add score in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, pdf, jupyter-notebook

How to loop through a folder to subfolders to convert pdf to text and generate the textscore of all in a dataframe?

Currently I'm able to get the last pdf file to convert to text and geenrate it scores and add it to a dataframe. But how do I do this to all the pdf files?

```py
import fitz
import os

path = "/Users/m/Desktop/books/"
dict1 = []
# for filename in os.listdir(books):
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for i in files:
        if i.endswith(".pdf"):
            # with fitz.open(path + "/" + i) as doc:
            with fitz.open(path + "/" + i) as doc:
                text = ""
                for page in doc:
                    text += page.getText()
                    continue
print(text)

from textatistic import Textatistic

x = Textatistic(text)
x.dict()
```

[pdf to text output pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hACgz.png)

```
import pandas as pd
text = []
text.append(x.dict())
df = pd.DataFrame(text)
df
```

[dataframe screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxpjH.png)

I want similar output for all the books in the same folder. I have like 100 books in a folder but this is only doing one book. How do I iterate all the books and have it in dataframe for each book like the above screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code within the loop, so that every book's statics is calculated and added to dataframe:

```
from textatistic import Textatistic
x = Textatistic(text)
x.dict()

import pandas as pd
text = []
text.append(x.dict())
df = pd.DataFrame(text)
```

Something like this should work:

```
import fitz
import os
## moved imports up here
from textatistic import Textatistic
import pandas as pd

path = "/Users/m/Desktop/books/"
dict1 = []
# for filename in os.listdir(books):

## empty text dictionary list before the loop
text = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for i in files:
        if i.endswith(".pdf"):
            #with fitz.open(path + "/" + i) as doc:
            with fitz.open(path + "/" + i) as doc:
                text = ""
                for page in doc:
                    text += page.getText()
                    continue
            ## for every loop (pdf book), textstatistics are retrieved and then converted to dictionary and then the dictionary is appended to the text list     
            print(text) 
            x = Textatistic(text)
            x.dict()
            text.append(x.dict())
            ## this can be moved outside the loop 
            df = pd.DataFrame(text)
```

Comment: Hi, it says AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: i think i figured it out, but now it says "ValueError: Word to be hyphenated may have at most 100 characters."

Comment: @Mick I'm not sure why you'd be getting that error. Maybe it has something to do with Textatistic function?

Comment: I read the textatistic documentation and googled a lot, but couldn't find any solution around that.

Comment: @Mick is something in one of the books you're processing? Maybe post another question on stackoverflow with the details.

Comment: How do i fix Hi, it says AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' in your code?